# Starting a java application as a service?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, java

How can we start a Java made application as a background process in Linux (Ubuntu).
In Windows using a .Net based application we could install it as a service.

So what is the professional and secure way ?

Initially my stupidity lead me to use Tomcat server :p

Edit: a little research suggest to use the command 'daemon' when starting a process in Ubuntu from the terminal

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The correct way to do this is to add init scripts

put a start and stop script into `/etc/init.d/` and then create symbolic links to these from `/etc/rc[runlevel].d/` to start and stop your service

For apache2, there is this script `/etc/init.d/apache2`

Start script: in `/etc/rc5.d`:

```
S91apache2 -> ../init.d/apache2
```

Kill script: in `/etc/rc6.d` and `/etc/rc1.d`

```
K09apache2 -> ../init.d/apache2
```

Sounds like you want rc5.d

for more detailed information read

```
/etc/init.d/README
```

For runlevels refer

- [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Runlevel)

More resources:

- [Linux.com](https://www.linux.com/news/enterprise/systems-management/8116-an-introduction-to-services-runlevels-and-rcd-scripts)

Comment: Many distributions (e.g. all Debian derivatives with `update-rc.d`) have tools to create the correct links in the `rc` directories. This also keeps track of start dependencies and other nice things, so make sure to see how it is supposed to be done in the distribution.

Comment: awesome, let me read the articles :)